# VB.NET How to disable javascript alert and javascript error in GeckoFX

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, geckofx

I'm actually creating a traffic exchange application and i need the surf to be easy without windows popping every second.

Actually, there are popups on my app with alert message, confirm message and others javascript errors, especially "Carroussel Errors" with Jquery.

I'm using GeckoFX 33 and i haven't found any solution in VB.NET language yet.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that implements nsIPromptService2 and nsIPrompt, and the methods that are in these interfaces allow custom handling of these events.

`internal class FilteredPromptService : nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt`

That's from a C# app, but I bet VB will be very similar.

In VB.NET try perhaps adding a class as follows:

`class FilteredPromptService Implements nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt`

Then in Visual studio right click on each interface and find an option - something like 'Implement interface' or 'Implement missing members'. If that's not there in VS 2013 express, then look at these two types in Object Browser and manually add all the methods and properties that are defined in the interface in your class.

Cheers:)

Comment: Do you've got any idea in VB.NET because i don't really now how to implement nsIPromptService2 and nsIPrompt in class ?

Comment: @LucasDuval Are you using visual studio? Which version?

Comment: I'm using VS Express 2013

Comment: Not really ! I've totally aborted this project